# How to assign values to cells of a dataframe efficiently iterating over another object

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dataframe, processing-efficiency

I got a generator object which basically consists of nested lists.
It contains around 20.000 lists, the structure looks like this:

```
cases = [[0,36,12],[64,28,1],....
```

Each list in this object represents rows that belong to one process. Now I want to assign a ProcessID to the respective rows of a dataframe. In the moment I achieve this using a for loop:

```
moc = df.iloc
processID = 0 
for process in cases:
  for step in process:
    moc[process,-1] = processID
  processID += 1
```

Even though this works, iterating through a for loop takes long, so I am interested in a more efficient way to assign the processID.

As I need to iterate over the cases object and since the length of the nested lists differ I do not know how to implement more efficient processes such as df.apply() or np.where().

Any help is appreciated.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cases = [[1,4,2],[3,5,0],[9,6],[7,8]]


d = {'col1': ["some_information", "some_information","some_information",
              "some_information","some_information","some_information", 
              "some_information","some_information","some_information",
              "some_information"],
    'processID':np.empty}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)
               col1                  processID
0  some_information  <built-in function empty>
1  some_information  <built-in function empty>
2  some_information  <built-in function empty>
3  some_information  <built-in function empty>
4  some_information  <built-in function empty>
5  some_information  <built-in function empty>
6  some_information  <built-in function empty>
7  some_information  <built-in function empty>
8  some_information  <built-in function empty>
9  some_information  <built-in function empty>

moc = df.iloc
processID = 1
for case in cases:
    for idx in case:
        moc[idx,-1] = processID

    processID += 1


print(df)
               col1 processID
0  some_information         2
1  some_information         1
2  some_information         1
3  some_information         2
4  some_information         1
5  some_information         2
6  some_information         3
7  some_information         4
8  some_information         4
9  some_information         3
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's a solution using dict comprehension with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.repeat.html) and [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to create `pandas.Series` that you can use to update your `DataFrame`. The benefit of this is there are no loops.

```
s = pd.Series({(i+1):x for i, x in enumerate(cases)})
processes = pd.Series(s.index.repeat(s.str.len()), index=np.hstack(s))
```

Based on your example `cases`, this will create a `Series` 'processes' like:

```
1    1
4    1
2    1
3    2
5    2
0    2
9    3
6    3
7    4
8    4
```

Then you can then assign into your `DataFrame`:

```
df['processID'] = processes
```

#### Testing performance

setup - creating a DataFrame of len 100,000 and random `cases` list:

```
idx = pd.Series(np.arange(100000)).sample(frac=1).values.tolist()
cases = [idx[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(idx), 3)]

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(100000),
                 'col2':['some_data']*100000})
```

Timing

```
%%timeit

s = pd.Series({(i+1):x for i, x in enumerate(cases)}).to_frame()
processes = pd.Series(s.index.repeat(s[0].str.len()), index=np.hstack(s[0]))
df['processID'] = processes

92.2 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```